# Recaptcha works locally, but not in production

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, recaptcha

I followed the instructions on how to add [Recaptcha](http://www.google.com/recaptcha) to my website (asp.net 4.0, Visual Studio / VB.  When I run the page locally, which is just a simple contact form page that sends an email, the recaptcha thing shows up fine.  I am NOT a programmer, though.

When I move it to production -- and I move the website (and the dll and pdb to the app_code folder and the bin folder, which Visual Studio created on its own), the page won't just refreshes and never sends an email -- and it doesn't matter if you type the right or wrong thing in the recaptcha textbox.  Without the recaptcha code, the contact.aspx page functions normally and sends the email instantly.

But the recaptcha box is there.  I've read things about **handler mappings** in IIS and my web.config, but I'm not intelligent enough to understand if I have to do anything or not, and what to do.  I also have IIS 7.0 on here.

**UPDATE:
When you enter the recaptcha information in the text box properly, the page displays the confirmation I encoded, and sends an email.  When you do NOT enter the recaptcha info correctly, instead of sending a "Please try again" message, it just refreshes the page and makes them start all over again.  It does not say "Please Try again" and doesn't leave the client with knowledge that they mistyped the code**

Comment: And what is this error you are getting?

Comment: Well, I should edit my question ... I wasn't clear.  The recaptcha shows up, but the email form doesn't work like it does without recaptcha.  It doesn't matter whether you get the recaptcha textbox filled out properly or not -- it just reloads the contact page and doesn't send the email.  Normally, it sends the email and stays on contact.aspx and says "Your message has been sent" -- now, it just refreshes the contact page and sends nothing.

Comment: Are you sure it re-captcha that's the problem? Are you able to send an email on production when re-captcha isnt on the page?

Comment: Hi Benni. When recaptcha is NOT on the page, email works fine.  When recaptcha is ON the page, it doesn't work -- the page just continues to refresh upon clicking the submit button.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you using the reCAPTCHA [ASP.NET control](http://code.google.com/apis/recaptcha/docs/aspnet.html) with the Recaptcha.dll?

You need to have signed up for the service with a domain name. The public and private keys you receive are checked against this domain:

> reCAPTCHA will only work on this domain and subdomains.

Notice it the admin page screenshot below:

[image: reCAPTCHA admin screen with keys]

But this rule does not apply on the localhost domain, which is what you use when developing with Visual Studio. So it may be that you are not using the keys that you received when registering your domain. When you select the control and switch from design view to code view in Visual Studio the control code should look like this, with the keys:

```
<recaptcha:RecaptchaControl ID="recaptcha" runat="server"
  PublicKey="6Lexn8wSAAAAAIfH1c3-6K3FbSjcKdMj3uiMImI7"
  PrivateKey="6Lexn8wSAAAAAKRFTJXTudJN1owrIQMDahwYv0hg" />
```

If not, you have to enter your keys. This is just an example, don't use these keys, use the keys displayed in your own account for your own domain.

Comment: I should update this.  Thank you for responding Michiel and Wiktor.  I had entered my keys and I even went to google.com/recaptcha to make new ones to test them.  Here is my issue now:  When I enter recaptcha CORRECT, the confirmation message shows up and I receive the email.  When I do NOT enter it correct, instead of giving me the "please try again" message, it just refreshes the page and does not give the client a message.  Any suggestions?  Thanks for your time!

Comment: I have this on my contactengineering.aspx page at the top:      <%@ Register TagPrefix="recaptcha" Namespace="Recaptcha" Assembly="Recaptcha" %>
                <script runat="server">
      Sub btnSubmit_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
          If Page.IsValid Then
              lblResult.Text = "You Got It!"
              lblResult.ForeColor = Drawing.Color.Green
          Else
              lblResult.Text = "Incorrect"
              lblResult.ForeColor = Drawing.Color.Red
          End If
      End Sub
  </script>

Comment: I have this within the form:                  <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBoxCC" runat="server" 
                    Text="<%$ Resources:LocalizedText, contacteng11 %>"></asp:CheckBox>
                <br />
                                  <recaptcha:RecaptchaControl
                  ID="recaptcha"
                  runat="server"
                  PublicKey="my public key"
                  PrivateKey="my private key"
                  />

Comment: And I have nothing on my codeback page, no other codings.  It's still just refreshing the page upon an incorrect entry.

Comment: (and I put in my public and private keys, just so you know)